# How to find the closest match to a string from ever-growing list of strings in Google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

The question is a bit complex, so I created this image:
[Question Scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwrSG.png)

You can find [the sample spreadsheet here.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11NIEtZHxm68-uJ3MriuutsDq-_FigfqKx8zHS5g3AKM/edit?usp=sharing)
For the sake of clarity, I have replaced actual data with alphabets.

**Details:**

- I have 10 fixed conditions, each with a specific weight attached to it.
- The conditions can be clubbed in multiple ways, creating a huge list of possible combinations. I have reduced it to less than 1000, by serializing it. This column is called "**All Conditions**".
- "**Available Conditions**" column shows the list of possible combinations that are available. This list will keep on growing till it matches exactly with "All Conditions" column.

**The challenge is:**
how to find the closest match to each value in "All Conditions" from "Available Conditions", taking into consideration the weightage?

For e.g., since 'A, B' is available, it will match. But for 'A, B, C', we need to find either 'A, B, C' or the combination with the highest weightage that is available, ie, 'A, B'.

Comment: Not sure I understand what are the criteria for finding the closest match. I understand that the `Weight` will be used, but how? Does the order of the conditions matter here? (for example, if we have ABC, AB could be a close match, but not BA?)

Comment: Yes, you are right - for ABC, AB & BC will be two options, of which since AB has higher weight, AB will be used. BA & CB cannot be used because those have been filtered prior to this step, by serializing from the possible combinations. Thus, order of the conditions is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an Apps Script [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#guidelines_for_custom_functions) that would do the following:

- Get all the `available` combos, the `fixed` conditions and `All` combos (this could be receive as a custom function argument). Split the comma-separated string to an array with all the different conditions (`A`, `B`, etc.).
- Loop through `All` combos, and for each one, do the following:
- Start a `while` loop that will loop through each condition in the combo, and filter out unmatching conditions until either (1) it gets to the end of the array and an exact match is found, or (2) no match is found and there's a list of candidates.
- Out of the possible candidates (if no match is found), find the candidate with the largest combinated weight.
- Return all the best matches.

#### Code snippet:

```
// Copyright 2021 Google LLC.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
function GET_CLOSEST_COMBOS(range) {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const available = sheet.getRange("A2:B").getValues().filter(row => row[0] !== "")
                         .map(row => [commaSeparatedToArray(row[0]), row[1]]);
  const fixedConditions = available.filter(av => av[1] !== "");
  const conditions = range.flat().map(conditionString => commaSeparatedToArray(conditionString));
  const bestMatches = conditions.map(condition => {
    let i = 0;
    let currentAvailable = [...available];
    while (i < condition.length) {
      const matchExists = currentAvailable.some(av => av[0][i] == condition[i]);
      if (matchExists) {
        currentAvailable = currentAvailable.filter(av => av[0][i] == condition[i]);
      } else {
        currentAvailable = currentAvailable.filter(av => av[0].length - 1 !== i);
      }
      if (!matchExists || (matchExists && i === condition.length - 1)) {
        const candidates = currentAvailable.map(av => {
          const weight = av[0].reduce((acc, current, index) => {
            return acc + fixedConditions.find(cond => cond[0] == current)[1];
          }, 0);
          return [av[0], weight];
        });
        const bestMatch = candidates.reduce((max, candidate) => max[1] >= candidate[1] ? max : candidate);
        return bestMatch[0].join(", ");
      }
      i++;      
    }
  });
  return bestMatches;
}

function commaSeparatedToArray(conditionString) {
  return conditionString.split(",").map(condition => condition.trim());
}
```

Once it is defined in the script, you can use it the same way you would any sheets built-in function. This function accepts the range corresponding to `All combinations` for which you want to retrieve the best match (in this case it would be `D2:D`).

#### Example:

[image]